# jQuery Ajax is not getting posted to a PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am new to AJAX so I know there could be a silly mistake in my code but anyways I will go ahead.

I have a function created that is called when a button is clicked. The function calls `.ajax()` method of jquery. I send the data to a file named 'delete_post.php`.

**HTML:**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="deletePost(<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>);">Yes</button>
```

The above code works.

**JS:**

```
function deletePost(postid) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "delete_post.php?id="+postid,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.error == true) console.log('error');
                    else console.log('problem?');
        }
    });
}
```

The above code is calling the `.ajax()` function but is not logging 'problem?' into the console.

Here's the PHP file:

```
<?php
require_once '...';
if(isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    echo "YEAH!";
} else {
    header("location: index.php");
}
?>
```

What's the issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try logging `data` itself?

Comment: no, the data is not JSON.

Comment: @JakubMichálek something is getting logged but nothing is shown

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan I get an error when I try `$.get`.

The Error is: `http://localhost/*hidden*/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: try `data == 'YEAH!'` instead..

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan In the PHP I should try that?

Comment: that should Happen. I'm sorry. anyway, can you try the condition I posted instead of data.error ==1 ?!!

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui - no in the Js instead of data.error == 1 try data == 'YEAH!'
if yes then no problem. else then there is a problem :0

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan the condition is not getting true

Comment: If you go to `delete_post.php?id={yourID}` directly, not using AJAX, do you see `YEAH!` or not?

Comment: what does firebug tell you when you log the data?

Comment: @JakubMichálek I get an error of PHP

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui in that case, fix the error :D

Comment: @JakubMichálek I am not getting how to fix that error: `Use of undefined constant data - assumed 'data'`

Comment: What is the PHP error?

Comment: The error is `Use of undefined constant data - assumed 'data'`

Comment: You need to use `$data` in PHP instead of just `data`. Don't mix languages... :)

Comment: @JakubMichálek What's `[object%20Object]` in the URL. This is the error I am getting continuosly in console.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38268/discussion-between-mohammad-areeb-siddiqui-and-jakub-michalek)

Comment: It means `postid` in your JS function is not an integer, but an object, so when it's put into a string, it says `[object Object]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as we discussed in the chat side, you can use it like this:

JS:

```
function deletePost(postid) { 
$.post('delete_post.php', {id : postid}, function(data){ 
console.log(data); 
}, 'json'); 
}
```

PHP:

```
 <?php 

    require_once '...'; 
    if(isset($_POST["id"])) { 
    $data['res'] = 'yes'; 
    echo json_encode($data); 
    } else { 
    header("location: index.php"); 
    } 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an escape issue in the following part:

```
onclick="deletePost(<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>);"
```

It must be as below:

```
onclick="deletePost(<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>);"
```

And, you are echoing 'YEAH!', so the if condition should be:

```
if(data == 'YEAH!')
```

Comment: No escaping is not needed, the inner `""` is in PHP, the outer is in HTML. ;)

Comment: Ofcourse this needs escaping or use a single quote. The whole html is a string and onclick will abruptly end when it encounters a matching double-quote

Comment: No, the output would be `onclick="deletePost(6);"` for example, no extra quotes there...

Answer (score 0):

Here is your working code, In your AJAX you are doing "POST" and in your PHP file your using "GET".

trigger.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function deletePost(postid) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://localhost/overflow/delete_post.php?id="+postid,
        success: function(data) {
           console.log('success:'+data);
        }, error: function(xhr, status, error){
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
</script>
</head>

<body>   

<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="deletePost(9); return false;">Yes</button>
</body>
</html>
```

delete_post.php

```
<?php
//require_once '...';
if(isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    echo "YEAH!";
     //do something
} else {
   // header("location: index.php");
     echo "not set";
}
?>
```

Try this and let us know your problem in detailed and clear. good luck