# Pass Array and String from Javascript to PHP with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax call.

My addList variable holds a string: list=Sports&list=Cars&list=Outdoor&new_list=123123

I want to grab the addList in my PHP file as

```
$_POST['list'] is an array with values Sports, Cars, Outdoor
$_POST['new_list'] is a string 123123
```

But I couldnt convert the POST string into right forms.

I can create arrays/loops in both sides but it didnt feel right.

Whats the convenient way of doing it?

```
jQuery.ajax({  
                    type: "post",  
                    url: ajax_var.url,  
                    data: "action=post-list&nonce="+ajax_var.nonce+"&post_list=&post_id="+post_id+"&" + addList,  
                    success: function(count){  
                        alert("done"); 
                    }  
                });
```

Any help will be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: [possible solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076841/jquery-ajax-is-not-getting-posted-to-a-php-file/19077227#19077227)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using followig code.

you just neeed to locate your form if and url to pass values to :

```
var form = new FormData($('#form_id')[0]);
form.append('view_type','addtemplate');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "savedata.php",
data: form,
cache: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false,
success:  function(data){
//alert("---"+data);
alert("Settings has been updated successfully.");
window.location.reload(true);
}
});
```

this will pass all form element automatically.

Working and tested code.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass variable with the ajax method from jQuery, you can pass array like this :

**jQuery**

```
    var myArray = newArray();
    myArray.push("data1");
    myString = "data2";


    jQuery.ajax({  
         type: "post",  
         url: ajax_var.url,  
         data: {array:myArray, param2:myString},
                  ^name     ^value
         success: function(count){  
             alert("done"); 
         }  
    });
```

**PHP**

```
echo $_POST['array'][0]; // data1
echo $_POST['param2']; // data2
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `addList` variable to this:

```
list[]=Sports&list[]=Cars&list[]=Outdoor&new_list=123123
```

PHP will parse the items named `list[]` into an array, and you'll find the values as `$_POST['list'][0]`,`$_POST['list'][1]`,`$_POST['list'][2]`